# automatically create subdomain, virtualhost and etc when add user

Tags: virtualhost, subdomain, automatic-updates, useradd

there is the way, how to automatically create the subdomain, virtualhost for apache, sharing configuration (samba), etc when I add a new user?

I want it's work like the web hosting service, when we registered, domain create automatically??

how to do that? or that is no way?

note: My server use debian 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've setup some shell scripts to somewhat automate the creation of new users, Apache virtual hosts, etc., but I'd imagine the shared hosting providers use something like [CPanel/WHM](http://www.cpanel.net/) or some homegrown automation.

EDIT

Looks like there are some open source alternatives to CPanel out there now.  Haven't tried any, hopefully another SF user can chime in as to quality:

http://www.vhcs.net/

http://www.virtualmin.com/

http://www.ispconfig.org/

More here, could be dated: http://wiki.debian.org/HostingControlPanels

Comment: OK. CPanel maybe the way for this. I'm the same with your imagine. But, I still learn about linux. I can't pay for CPanel license, that not suit for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're literally using `adduser`, then there's support for an adduser.local file, and there should be an example of one in `/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local`. Copy it to `/usr/local/sbin`, edit it to your needs, and it will be used anytime you run `adduser`.